# shell script to map fields and return the corresponding value from list

Tags: scripts

```
Symbol  Test  
XXX,1  
GHL,2  
MKT,13  
LOC,15  
LMT,76  
TIF,45
```

Shell script should return corresponding symbol for each Test.

If `$Test=1`,then `$symbol` should be `XXX`

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `bash` associative array :

```
declare -A foobar
while read -r foo bar; do foobar["$bar"]="$foo"; done < <(tail -n +2 file.txt)
```

This will generate an associative array named `foobar` by reading the lines starting from second line from the file containing the key-value mapping.

Now you can declare a small function like :

```
choose () { echo "${foobar["$1"]}" ;}
```

It will output the value stored on the specified key given as first argument.

Example :

```
$ choose 2
GHL
$ choose 1
XXX
```

Comment: Interesting. note that this assumes the mapping is unique. It may be, but may not.

Comment: @fedorqui yeah, it will show the last mapping in non-unique cases, i have taken OP's example literally though and the numbers should be unique btw although not sure..

Comment: Yes, the OP did not give much information so I think it is fine to assume it is unique. I used `awk` to avoid this, but it shouldn't matter. +1 for the good approach!

Answer (score 1):

This just needs a little bit of `awk`:

```
awk -v var=1 '$2 == var {print $1}' your_file
```

That is, look for the lines having the 2nd field equal to the given variable `var`; when this happens, print the first field.

Comment: @fedorqui...If I have the delimiter as , in my file instead of =.where should I replace?

Comment: @canonical first of all, you should edit your question giving a real sample input. Then, you could say `awk -F, '...' file`.

Answer (score 0):

Python can do the job too:

```
python -c 'import sys;print [i.split(",")[0] for x,i in enumerate(sys.stdin) if x > 0 and i.strip().split(",")[1] == sys.argv[1]]' 13  < input.txt
```

Or as actual script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for x,i in enumerate(sys.stdin): 
    if x > 0 and i.strip().split(",")[1] == sys.argv[1]:
         print i.strip().split(",")[0]
```

Test run:

```
$ python find_line.py 76 < input.txt                                                                                         
LMT
```

The way this works is simple: we redirect `input.txt` into script's `stdin` and then read it line by line, skipping first line and splitting lines into list using comma.  The desired number to look up is given as first command-line argument.

It would make much easier if there wasn't the header line - that would eliminate `enumerate()` call, and simplify line check to `if i.strip().split(",")[1] == sys.argv[1]`